# Fitting coefficients on data so that the ratio of each variable is close to one - R

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, model-fitting

I have data that looks like this :

```
head(df)
player                 monday         tuesday  wednesday thursday       friday      saturday
  <chr>                 <dbl>           <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>
1 Jack                     15              12         NA       6            NA            NA  
2 John                     22              18         7        NA           NA            NA  
3 Peter                    NA              NA         NA       NA           17.4          29.7
4 Jan                      NA              10         NA       4            NA            NA  
5 Mike                     32              NA         NA       18.7         NA            NA  
6 Jason                    NA              NA         NA       NA           11            14
```

Every player performs at a different level. What I want to know is the effect that day has on performance as increase/decrease proportion of a base. So if we assume base Monday for Jack, Tuesday is 0.8 of Monday's performance.

My thought is that I need to fit coefficients for each day using least squares of the difference between 1 and the ratio of pairwise performance numbers. But I'm not sure how to do that.

Although maybe I'm over complicating, and there's a better way of tackling this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How should your expected output look like ?

Comment: I really just want the 6 coefficients which I can order so I can use the rule of thumb "performance is x% better on this day compared to that day"

Comment: What about taking the ratio between each value and the row's median? Would that achieve your goal?

Comment: Look up packages with a returns function and `apply(df, 1, returns)`?

Comment: I don't think either of these help me. Essentially, there are a set of 6 coefficients for each day that minimise the residual sum of squares of the ratio between each of the columns and 1.